# Recover deleted folder from Google VPS

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, delete-file

We have a VPS running on Google Cloud which had a very important folder in a user directory. An employee of ours deleted that folder and we can't seem to figure out how to recover it. I came across `extundelete` but it seems the partition needs to be unmounted for it to work but I don't understand how I would do it on Google. This project took more than a year and that was the latest copy after a fire which took out the last copy from our local servers.

Could anyone please help or guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting any files back from your VM's disk may be tricky (at best) or  impossible (most probably) if the files got overwritten.**

Easiest way would be to get them back from a copy or snapshot of your VM's disk. If you have a [snapshot of your disk](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/introducing-scheduled-snapshots-for-compute-engine-persistent-disk) (either taken manually or automatically) from before when the folder in question got delete then you will get your files back.

If you don't have any backups then you may try to recover the files - I've found many guides and tutorials, let me just link the ones I believe would help you the most:

- [Unix/Linux undelete/recover deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80285/404591)
- [Recovering accidentally deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-accidentally-deleted-files)
- [Get list of files deleted by rm -rf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366145/get-list-of-files-deleted-by-rm-rf)

### ------------- UPDATE -----------

**Your last chance in this battle is to make two clones of the disk**
and then [detach original disk from the VM and attach](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk) one of the clones to keep your VM running. Then use second clone for any experiments. **Keep the original untouched** in case you mess up the second clone.

Now create a new Windows VM and attach your second clone as the additional disk. At this moment you're ready to try various data redovery software;

- [UFS Explorer](https://www.ufsexplorer.com/)
- [Virtual Machine Data Recovery](https://www.stellarinfo.com/disk-recovery/virtual-machine-recovery.php)

There are plenty of others to try from too.

Another approach would be to create an image from the original disk and export it as a VMDK imagae (and save it to a storage bucket). Then download it to yor local computer and then use for example [VMware VMDK Recovery](https://www.sysinfotools.com/recovery/vmdk-recovery.php) or other specialized software for extracting data from virtual machines disk images.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I unfortunately don't have any copy. I had a feeling I was out of luck but I still wanted to try my luck here. I'll accept this as the answer and try those links.
Again, thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Bad luck - although (hopefully) not all is lost. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give it a shot today and post an update.